# Update with wp_update_post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Problem: when the WP field *post_date* is updated, the field *post_date_gmt* is also supposed to be updated as well, however it is not.  I found the function that are doing the update in one of the plugins:

```
 function KBM_Reposter_move_oldest_post($kbm_Reposter_Catagory_ID) {
 global $logrr;
 $logrr -> logDebug("Start: " . __FUNCTION__);
  $kbm_Reposter_Get_Post_Arguments = array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => 1, 'category' => $kbm_Reposter_Catagory_ID, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC');
  $kbm_Reposter_Old_Posts = get_posts($kbm_Reposter_Get_Post_Arguments);
  if ($kbm_Reposter_Old_Posts) {
   foreach($kbm_Reposter_Old_Posts as $kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post) {
    $kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post->post_date = date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $result = wp_update_post($kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post);
    if (!is_wp_error($result) AND $result > 0) {
        $logrr -> logNotice("Post updated, id=$result");
    }
   }
  } else {
    $logrr -> logNotice("No post found for repost!");
  }
  $logrr -> logDebug("End: " . __FUNCTION__);
 }
```

The wp_update_post updates the fields.  I think the line that needs changing is this:

```
$kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post->post_date = date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

How to update *post_date_gmt* field with the same date as part of the wp_update_post?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post->post_date_gmt = date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

to this

```
$kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post->post_date = date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post->post_date_gmt = date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i:s',false,true);
```

This will set the gmt field as well. The date_i18n function here already converts the time to GMT time since the third parameter is set to true, more on that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n

Comment: With that will post_date_gmt contains the gmt equivalent of post_date?

Comment: yes, exactly. IF you do not want the gmt equivavlent but just want the same date as in post_date, use $kbm_Reposter_Oldest_Post->post_date_gmt = date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i:s');